# How do I annotate with @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") for a single cast instead of a whole method?

Tags: java, annotations, suppress-warnings

It seems excessive when annotations apply to a method.

How do I use the annotation @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") for a single cast instead of a whole method?

In this example, I just finished checking that a cast will be safe and so I proceed to cast but I get an annoying warning.

```
@Override
public void execDetails()
{ 
    Map<Integer, ResponseList<?>> responseMap = 
            new HashMap<Integer, ResponseList<?>>();

    // ... omitted code ...

    ResponseList<?> responseList = responseMap.get(requestId);
    Class<?> elementType = responseList.getElementType();
    if (elementType == ExecutionDetail.class)
        ((ResponseList<ExecutionDetail>)responseList).add(new ExecutionDetail());

}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `@SuppressWarnings` for a single variable declaration:

```
public static List<String> foo(List<?> list) {
    List<String> bad = (List<String>) list;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<String> good = (List<String>) list;
    return good;
}
```

It has to be at the point of the local variable declaration though:

> Annotations may be used as modifiers in any declaration, whether package (§7.4), class (§8), interface, field (§8.3, §9.3), method (§8.4, §9.4), parameter, constructor (§8.8), or local variable (§14.4).

Comment: It appears that the annotation helps only if the cast and the variable declaration are in the same statement.

Comment: @broiyan: Yes, that wouldn't surprise me - but you can always introduce an extra local variable just for the sake of that statement :)

Comment: That can get very ugly in a switch block because of shared scope.

Answer (score 3):

You can extract a method for that one line and suppress for that line/method.

Many tools/ides have there own ways of doing this such as placing the annotation on the local variable, but I don't believe all compilers supports this.